# Use the GPU on another process when it is available(Nice-like command for GPU)

Tags: linux, kernel, gpu, nice, cuda

I have a program that uses a lot of GPU power. During some epochs, for example, it takes a job and processes it, and then waits about 10 to 15 minutes before taking the next job. When the main program is in waiting mode, GPU is free. I'd like to use that time to process another task in the second program.

I want to find out if the main program does not use the GPU, the second program does. This is something like the nice command but used for GPUs.
What is the best way to achieve that?

**Basically, we want to prioritize tasks for GPU.**